# C# ASP.NET - SImplify number of SQL queries written in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Here's a little background on what I'm doing...

I'm writing a C# web app.  On the main page, I have a data input form with about 25 individual Dropdownlists.  I created a table called options, and it's pretty simple (ID, Category, Option).  Each option I create is categorized so my query will only include options that match the category I'm looking up. Each Category matches one of the 25 Dropdownlists I need to populate.

So I'm able to get a few of these populated on the form and they work great.  I'm concerned that the re-writing of this code (with slight variation of the DDlist name and category name) will cause the code to be much longer.  Is there a way I can create a class of it's own and pass parameters to the class so it only returns me data from the correct category and populates the correct Dropdownlist?  Here's some sample code I have so far for 2 DD fields.  The DDStationList and DDReqeustType are the names of 2 of the 25 Dropdownlists I have created:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Drawing;
namespace TEST
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        //Main connection string
        string SqlConn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SqlConn"];     
        string qryRequestType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["qryRequestTypes"];
        string qryStationNumbers = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["qryStationNumbers"];
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {}
        protected void BtnAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //GET Request Types
            DataTable RequestTypes = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(SqlConn);
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(qryRequestType, Conn);
                adapter.Fill(RequestTypes);
                DDRequestType.DataSource = RequestTypes;
                DDRequestType.DataTextField = "Option";
                DDRequestType.DataValueField = "Option";
                DDRequestType.DataBind();
            }
            // Get Stations
            DataTable Stations = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(SqlConn);
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(qryStationNumbers, Conn);
                adapter.Fill(Stations);
                DDStationList.DataSource = Stations;
                DDStationList.DataTextField = "Option";
                DDStationList.DataValueField = "Option";
                DDStationList.DataBind();
            }
        }
        protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //More stuff to do here for submit code
        }
    }
}
```

Example queries from my config file that correspond to above code:

```
SELECT [Option] FROM Table WHERE Category = 'RequestType';
SELECT [Option] FROM Table WHERE Category = 'Station';
```

So, is it possible I can create a class that I can pass the Option's Category into that runs the query Like this:

```
SELECT [Option] FROM Table WHERE Category = @Category;
```

...and then populate the correct Dropdownlist (need to do this 25 times)?

If I'm not clear on my question, I'll be happy to explain further.

Comment: Regarding, `Is there a way I can create a class of it's own and pass parameters to the class so it only returns me data from the correct category and populates the correct Dropdownlist`, you might be better of adding a function to your current class.

Comment: Can you send me an example, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create a stored procedure instead?

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dc.Con)) {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetCategory", con)) {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;    
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Category", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCategory.Text;

        con.Open();
        var results = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
}
```

OR include the parameter

```
string sql = "SELECT [Option] FROM Table WHERE Category = @Category";

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dc.Con)) {
    using (SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Category", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCategory.Text;
        con.Open();
        var results = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
}
```

EDIT

```
class Category
{
    /* properties */

    /* method */
    public List<Category> GetCategory(string selectedCategory) 
    { /* Method statements here */ }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was actually going to convert to to a Stored Proc once I have the method to this madness down.  How can I use your example to bind it to the Dropdownlist?

Comment: Create a function for the class, and assign the result to the drop downlist. Make sense?

Comment: A stored procedure that returns a resultset can be bound to a dropdownlist. Just set it as the DataSource. i.e. `DDStationList.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();` Better still would be to use something like `SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); DDStationList.DataSource = dr;`